# Associate file extension with app in wp7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to associate a particular file extension with my app in wp7.1?
I would like to allow the users of my app to email files of a particular type to each other and then when they click on the attached email file  it would launch my app so it could process the file and add it to isolated storage.

Comment: I know registering protocol handlers is not possible.  Not sure about file extensions, but my guess is no.  Hopefully I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. You need a "special permission" from Microsoft to do it, that's how Adobe was allowed to do it.

But there's no part of the official released SDK that allows for it.