# How to register an app as a default viewer for a file type in WP 7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm getting quite a few emails with logs in XML format attached and I want to associate my own app with the XML file type on Windows Phone Mango, overwriting the default xml viewer.

If overwriting isn't possible I can get the logs generated with a custom extension. I would then need to associate the extension with my app same way Adobe Reader does it for PDFs.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to set your app as the default viewer for any file extension. The closest you can get at the moment is using [extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202966%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). However, these are limited to Photos, Music and Search and not custom extensions. (Even then, your app wouldn't be the default viewer, but it would be accessible from the respective hubs).

Comment: How does Adobe do it with PDF files then?

Comment: I'm guessing Adobe has access to certain native functions like other selected partner apps. Happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @keyboardP No, I think you are correct. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068729/associate-file-extension-with-app-in-wp7-1) has the same conclusion.

Comment: It would be nice if they made it possible to register your app as the default but I suspected that it was impossible for those without permission to be able to do it. If OP wants to, they can suggest it here http://wpdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping this isn't going to be the case. The more I try to do with Windows Phone lately the more restricted it seems to me.